# Export Access Report Design to rdlc

Tags: ms-access, export, rdlc

I have an old Access-File. Within this file are many Reports. Is there a Way to export the Design (Layout) of the Reports so i can use it in c#? Like an RDLC-File?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Reports in Access (any version) are very much different from reports in Visual Studio, regarding design as well as operation.

Answer (score 0):

You need SQL Server Data Tools extension installed on your Visual Studio and in an Empty SSRS project. Once opened go to "Project" in the file menu and there is a button that looks like this.

[Import Reports Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7Zzf.png)

I have only tested it on very simple access reports but, it seems to work. It gets you about halfway there to converting to these silly access reports.